# Is there any way to the get object that was tapped on in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've read the apple docs on the [responder chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009071-CH1-SW1) and needed to know: How is it do i NSLog the object that was tapped on?

Let's say I have a very complex view controller with multiple views object, when ever i tap on an object (UIButton or what ever..) is there a way to know that particular object that was tapped on?
The docs gave a good overview, but wasnt to clear in methods to overwrite.

**EDIT**:
The situation is in testing different apps i have not written. I need a quick  way to determine the Object that was tapped on (as many apps have custom controls/object that looks like one thing, but is really another). I was hoping there was some way to intercept the touch event right as it was being sent to UIAppication, and then NSLog it.

Comment: You need methods that respond to the taps.  Each of them can determine what caused its tap.  (If you need to know that after the event processing is over, you could create some kind of `id lastTapTarget` variable and save it.)

Comment: According to the docs, it says that the event objects first get sent to UIApplication, then to the window, then to the view. Is there a way to intercept those events while its getting there? I would not want to start writing tap methods for a bunch of objects in an app i dont own

Comment: How do you think of noticing that there was a tap at all? There are several ways to answer your question. For UIControl subclasses you could always define actions that are invoked when a certain touch was made. If you just follow touch events then you may need to get the coordinates of the couch and determine which UIView currently occupies the space in question. There are more options. Really, it depends. Please provide a bit more background to your situaiton.

Comment: @user76859403 - You need the methods regardless of what you want to log if the intent of tapping is for the user to invoke some kind of app behavior.  (And what do you mean by "objects in an app i dont own"?)

Comment: i just updated the question

Comment: Does that mean you are testing but also in a position to change the source code?  Or are you trying to get information about a pre-built app?

Comment: I have access to the source code. But would like to make minimal code change as possible, as there are a lot of apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent]` to do what you want:

```
@implementation MyApplicationSubclass

- (BOOL)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target from:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Sending action %@ from sender %@ to target %@ for event %@", NSStringFromSelector(action), sender, target, event);
    return [super sendAction:action to:target from:sender forEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Put that in a custom subclass of UIApplication. Then, in main.m, change the call to `UIApplicationMain()` so that your custom subclass is used:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MyApplicationSubclass class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Note that this only works for UIControl subclasses, which send their actions to their targets using this mechanism. If you want to see all touch events going through an app, override `-[UIApplication sendEvent:]` instead. In that case, it will be up to you to figure out which object is *going* to receive the touch. You can do that with by calling `-hitTest:` on your main view/window, though keep in mind that that figures out which view the touch lands on, not necessarily which view handles it (views can forward events to other objects, for example). Something like this:

```
@implementation MyApplicationSubclass

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIWindow *window = [self keyWindow];
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesForWindow:window];
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        UIView *touchedView = [window hitTest:[touch locationInView:window] withEvent:event];
        NSLog(@"Touch %@ received in view %@ for event %@", touch, touchedView, event);
    }

    [super sendEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Comment: genius. thanks! I modified my code just a lil bit, but this should do nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

For a button the action method normally has that param,

```
- (void)action:(id)sender {
```

Here sender represents the button. You can use it as,

```
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   button.hidden = YES;//use the properties of button now
```

You can also check with the [UITouch delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a) methods.

For eg:-

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];// or UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

       CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:myViewToCheck];
       if (CGRectContainsPoint(myViewToCheck.bounds, point) ) {
           //Touch detected on myViewToCheck.
       }
```

Comment: That is right. I just don't think that is what he has asked for.

Comment: Ok. its not only, for a button.. Is there a way to have the ability to Log any control that was tapped on the screen? The controls can be literally anything including custom controls in all their forms.

Comment: @HermannKlecker, Is it? Sorry, then I think I am confused with question. Let me check again.

Comment: I am confused by the question too :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to look at https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect.

Straight from github: Introspect is small set of tools for iOS that aid in debugging user interfaces built with UIKit.

It has a logging component that may be of use?

Comment: That's a bit overkill for the task needed. Ive saved that link though. Thanks.